# C - Simple ipv6 udp server using select to listen on multiple ports. Receiving message from one port, not the other

Tags: c, sockets, udp, client-server, ipv6

Here is my code.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int max(int socket_handle[]);

int main( void )
{
   int       max_clients_allowed = 2;
   int       socket_handle[max_clients_allowed];
   int       client_handle[max_clients_allowed];
   struct    sockaddr_in6 server_address[max_clients_allowed];
   struct    sockaddr_in6 client_address[max_clients_allowed];
   char      buffer[1000];
   socklen_t client_length;
   fd_set    read_handles;
   struct    timeval timeout_interval;
   int       bytes_received;
   int       port_number = 9000;
   int       retval;
   int       i;


   printf("Hello, human.\n");

   for (i = 0; i < max_clients_allowed; i++)
   {
       printf("Creating socket%d on port: %d\n", i, port_number + i);
       socket_handle[i] = socket(PF_INET6,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
       memset( &server_address[i], 0, sizeof( server_address[i] ) );
       server_address[i].sin6_family = AF_INET6;
       server_address[i].sin6_addr=in6addr_any;
       server_address[i].sin6_port=htons( port_number + i );

       if(bind( socket_handle[i], (struct sockaddr *)&server_address[i], sizeof( server_address[i] )) < 0)
       {
           perror("Unable to bind.");
           return -1;
       }
       else
       {
           printf("Bind %d successful.\n", i);
       }

   }



   while (1) {

       FD_ZERO(&read_handles);
       FD_SET(socket_handle[0], &read_handles);
       FD_SET(socket_handle[1], &read_handles);
       timeout_interval.tv_sec = 2;
       timeout_interval.tv_usec = 500000;
       retval = select(max(socket_handle) + 1, &read_handles, NULL, NULL, &timeout_interval);
       if (retval == -1)
       {
           printf("Select error\n");
           //error
       }
       else if ((retval = 0))
       {
           printf("timeout\n");
       }
       else
       {
           //good
           client_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr*);
           for (i = 0; i < max_clients_allowed; i++)
           {
              if (FD_ISSET(socket_handle[i], &read_handles))
              {
                  if((bytes_received = recvfrom(socket_handle[i],buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address[i], (socklen_t*)&client_length)) < 0)
                  {
                     perror("Error in recvfrom.");
                     break;
                  }
                  printf("\nData received:");
                  printf("\n--------------\n");
                  printf("%s", buffer);
            }
           }
       }
   }
}

int max(int socket_handle[])
{
    if (socket_handle[0] > socket_handle[1])
    {
        return socket_handle[0];
    }
        return socket_handle[1];
}
```

This code is supposed to bind to port 9000 and 9001.  It them uses select to see which sockets has incoming data, and then prints the message.

I'm assuming it has something to do with my recvfrom function.  I've tried playing around with the parameters with no avail.

Another problem might be when I am setting up the sockets, I am using sin6.addr = in6addr_any. I'm pretty sure PF_INET6 and AF_INET6 are right, but that could be an issue too.  I've been playing with this for a bit but I can't find the bug.  I would be really grateful if someone could point out my mistake so I could fix it.  I know I'm on the cusp of getting this finished.

This is a homework problem, the teacher gave us the test program and all it does is simply send a message on port 9000.

Comment: Please show your code here -- pastebin.com is overloaded and won't let me look.

Comment: Pastebin is down right now. Please strip down your code to the bare minimum needed to demonstrate your problem and then edit your question to show the actual code here.

Comment: @Barmer code copy/pasted here

Comment: @Remy Thanks, copied/pasted code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

When calling `recvfrom()`, you are setting the `client_length` to the wrong value on input.  It needs to be set to `sizeof(client_address[I])` instead.  You also need to reset the `client_length` each time you call `recvfrom()`.

When you print the received `buffer`, you need to take `bytes_received` into account since the buffer will not be null-terminated (unless the client is sending null-terminated data).

Try this instead:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    int       max_servers = 2;
    int       server_handle[max_servers];
    int       max_server_handle = 0;
    struct    sockaddr_in6 server_address[max_servers];
    struct    sockaddr_in6 client_address[max_servers];
    char      buffer[1000];
    socklen_t client_length;
    fd_set    read_handles;
    struct    timeval timeout_interval;
    int       bytes_received;
    int       port_number = 9000;
    int       retval;
    int       i;

    printf("Hello, human.\n");

    for (i = 0; i < max_servers; i++)
    {
        printf("Creating socket %d on port: %d\n", i, port_number + i);

        server_handle[i] = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (server_handle[i] < 0)
        {
            perror("Unable to create socket.");
            return -1;
        }

        if (server_handle[i] > max_server_handle)
            max_server_handle = server_handle[i];

        memset( &server_address[i], 0, sizeof( server_address[i] ) );
        server_address[i].sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        server_address[i].sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
        server_address[i].sin6_port = htons( port_number + i );

        if (bind( server_handle[i], (struct sockaddr *)&server_address[i], sizeof( server_address[i] )) < 0)
        {
            perror("Unable to bind.");
            return -1;
        }

        printf("Bind %d successful.\n", i);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&read_handles);
        for (i = 0; i < max_servers; i++)
            FD_SET(server_handle[i], &read_handles);

        timeout_interval.tv_sec = 2;
        timeout_interval.tv_usec = 500000;

        retval = select(max_server_handle + 1, &read_handles, NULL, NULL, &timeout_interval);
        if (retval == -1)
        {
            printf("Select error\n");
            //error
        }
        else if (retval == 0)
        {
            printf("timeout\n");
        }
        else
        {
            //good
            for (i = 0; i < max_servers; i++)
            {
                if (FD_ISSET(server_handle[i], &read_handles))
                {
                    client_length = sizeof(client_address[i]);

                    if ((bytes_received = recvfrom(server_handle[i], buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address[i], &client_length)) < 0)
                    {
                        perror("Error in recvfrom.");
                        break;
                    }

                    printf("\nData received on socket %d:", i);
                    printf("\n--------------\n");
                    printf("%.*s", bytes_received, buffer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My mistake.  I had the ipv6 versions.

Comment: Besides the printf statement down at the bottom, this is what I had when I thought I had finished this, before all fiddling.  It doesn't give me any errors.  This is the out put:

Data receive:\n
--------------\n
Sent to port 9000\n
Data receive:\n
--------------\n

"Sent to port 9000" is the message sent from the client.  It should also say "Sent to port 9001". So, the recv function is successful both times, but I'm not getting the string for the message. Wireshark shows that both packets are valid.  edit:I wish I could put line breaks in here..

Comment: I already passed it in.  It wasn't working.  The only thing I mirrored from you code was this one line "printf("%.*s", bytes_received, buffer);" thanks for the help! :]

Comment: Then it may be a problem with your client code.  Can you please update your question with your latest server code, and add your client code?